# How do i mix stdin streams in ffmpeg?

Tags: java, ffmpeg, stream, stdin

Basically I'm getting two separate raw data streams, one is video which comes in raw x264 or x265 format which i can capture with:

`ffmpeg -y -re -probesize 512 -framerate 30000/1001 -i - -c:v copy /some/output.ts`

And another stream which is pcm audio which I can get by running:
`ffmpeg -y -f s16le -ar 44100 -ac 2 -i - /output.wav`

While each of those separate commands works and the output is fine, I can't mix those in a single command because they both receive stdin, and I'm running this from Java so I cant (at least don't know how to) use the pipe: protocol, I tried writing raw information to fifo file, but ffmpeg crashes saying there is bad data, synchronization is currently not an issue, just need to understand how can I write two streams into ffmpeg from stdin or any other way to do so.

Comment: A fifo (named pipe) is probably your best option. What did you try regarding that?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard fifo result in a bad data message

Comment: What did you actually try? Show the command and complete console output.